# GET requests to Zendesk API fail using Python 3.x with the HTTP code 401 Unauthorised

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests, zendesk-api

I'm simply testing out the capabilities of Zendesk API with the intention of creating a ticket-based Slack application but I cannot seem to get past the simple act of authenticating myself.

I am using a token for authentication and the requests library as instructed on [Zendesk's help desk](https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001074168-Making-requests-to-the-Zendesk-API) but I still seem to be getting the same

> Status: 401 Problem with the request. Exiting.

error message.

I currently have two versions of a Python3 code that have the same output each time.

**Passing the Authorization header**

```
import requests
import base64

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json'
user = 'email'
pwd = 'token'

# Create the basic auth header
auth = user + '/token:' + pwd
auth = auth.encode("utf-8")
auth = base64.b64encode(auth)
auth = auth.decode("utf-8")
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth}

# Do the HTTP get request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
    exit()

# Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
data = response.json()
print(data.text)
```

**Using auth tuple in the requests.get function**

```
import requests

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json'
user = 'email' + '/token'
pwd = 'token'

# Do the HTTP get request
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd))

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
    exit()

# Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
data = response.json()
print(data.text)
```

I have also tried cURL which seems to be working without any hiccups. My guess is that it has something to do with how requests library is coded, however, I could not seem to find the answer anywhere.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show us the curl command that is working correctly.

Comment: If the username really is `email/token` and the password really is `token`, then the second example ought to work.

Comment: I would screenshot the terminal and provide it here but Stack Overflow does not allow it and copying the text, of course, includes some private information. But here's an example cURL that I just ran and went through just fine: curl https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/28862.json -v -u email/token:token

Comment: That curl command is fetching `tickets/28862.json`, not `tickets.json`.  I don't know if that is a meaningful difference or not.

Comment: Also, curl identifies itself as as different `User-Agent` than requests does.  Have you tried sending a different User-Agent header?

Comment: My bad, should have used the same one, it's just that I did not want to overflow my screen with meaningless text. Essentially anything that I try with cURL works just as intended - be it groups.json, tickets.json or any other request

Comment: Hmm, are you saying that I should try a different `User-Agent` with the Python script? Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, that's the only difference I can think of between the two methods.  You can explicitly set a User-Agent value in the request headers.

Comment: I will look into that and follow-up in case of any positive outcome. Thanks!

Comment: Also, it's possible that the response body contains an actual helpful error message.  Try printing it.

Comment: Alright so I have tried changing the `User-Agent` to various properties but it did not seem to make a difference. As for the body, it simply returns: {"error":"Couldn't authenticate you"}

Comment: Your comment with the sample curl command is a bit ambiguous -- it appears as `curl domain.zendesk.com/...`, but on mouseover it appears as `curl https://domain.zendesk.com/...`.  Are you using `https://` in the curl command?

Comment: Yeah, it is indeed `https://...` I suppose it's just Stack Overflow doing its magic.

Comment: I suppose I will just call a bash script with the curl command and return the output as a str. That's gonna be messy but it's better than nothing. Thanks for your help anyway, I'm always open to hearing new ideas if anything would come up.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the docs you need to enable password and email as auth

https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/getting-started/zendesk-api-quick-start/#preparation

Comment: Considering that linked content is not considered part of an answer at StackOverflow, yours is ... brief. Consider adding more explanation or a summary of the linked description of how to do it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31616232)